# Why not compare e.key directly instead of assigning it to a variable?

Tags: java, hashmap

While reading the source code for `HashMap`, I came across this snippet in `public V put(K key, V value)`:

```
for (Entry<K,V> e = table[i]; e != null; e = e.next) {
    Object k;
    if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k))) {
        V oldValue = e.value;
        e.value = value;
        e.recordAccess(this);
        return oldValue;
    }
}
```

Why assign `e.key` to `k` for comparing? Why not compare directly, like:

```
if (e.hash == hash && (e.key == key || key.equals(e.key))
```

------------------- UPDATE ------------------------

According to the answer from @seand, I do more detail investigation:

```
import com.test.Test;

    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Test t = new Test();
            int a = t.a;
            int b = a;
        }
    }
```

class Test has a int filed a;

Using javap -c Main to get the class file content:

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
Code:
   0: new           #2                  // class test/Test
   3: dup           
   4: invokespecial #3                  // Method test/Test."<init>":()V
   7: astore_1      
   8: aload_1       
   9: getfield      #4                  // Field test/Test.a:I
  12: istore_2      
  13: iload_2       
  14: istore_3      
  15: return
```

`int a = t.a` represents

```
8:[load the t object]
9:[access the field a]
12:[store the value to a]
```

Refer to [jvm specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/Instructions2.doc5.html) get information of [getfield]

`int b = a` represents:

```
13:[load the local variable]
14:[store the value to b];
```

It seems reasonable to access the local variable than the class field.

Comment: Probably as a (questionable) optimization.

Comment: @Minitech: don't be afraid, the gods didn't intervene. It was just me, their messenger.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: What?

Comment: @SLaks for volatile variable, it is reasonable to to like this, refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking#cite_note-5, however, I don't know why here.

Comment: @minitech: merged edits. Looks like I'll need to work on my messenger skills.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: Oh. Unless we made the exact same changes, that sounds more like a bug!

Comment: @minitech: It's intentional as far as I know. If you commit at the exact same time it merges the commits and gives preference to the one that made the most substantial changes (the first line is mine, the rest is yours). It's a feature, sadly ;)

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: You mean “While reading the source code…”? Then we literally wrote the exact same thing. Whoa. :D

Comment: @minitech the question and description are more clear than before, thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

My guess is it's an optimization which saves an extra lookup to e.key.  (Though it's not actually a method call that's using invokevirtual, it may save a level of indirection).  Since this is a very heavily used library function the authors likely used every trick they could think of for maximum performance.  You can also see how it checks for object identity in `k = e.key` which may avoid a slightly more costly `equals()` call.

Comment: This is true especially for String, where hash is calculated only once, while bucket traversal might happen many times.

Comment: Your explanation sounds reasonable, but with e.hash == hash instead of equals(), the reason is the hash is primitive type int.